# SharePoint REST API - How To Enable Incoming Email On A List

Tags: 2013, rest

am trying to migrate SharePoint 2010 code to SharePoint 2013 using the REST API. I have a list that is created dynamically, and one of the settings I need to enable, is to allow incoming email into the list.

In SharePoint 2010, in context, the code was easy:

```
SPList dropBox = oWeb.Lists["Dropbox"];
dropBox.EnableAssignToEmail = true;
dropBox.EmailAlias = "dropbox";
dropBox.Update();
```

How do I recreate this functionality with the REST API calls? I can't seem to find anything about this in the Microsoft documentation, nor in a Google search. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and MSDN Rest API references for List, I don't there is equivalent API available for enable Incoming Email settings from REST API.

You can use same Server object model for enabling these settings, as there is no equivalent API in present in CSOM.